# RestEasy : send a JSON in a GET request

Tags: java, json, resteasy

I'm trying to send a small JSON in a GET Request but I can't get it to work

```
String myJson = "{ \"money\":"+500+" }";
Response r = target.get(Entity.json(myJson));
```

How can I do ?

I have this error message:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Entity<String> to Class<T>
```

Comment: How exactly is it not working?  Are you getting a null response for `r`?

Comment: Could you please share the stack trace if you're getting any error to answer more effectively ?

Comment: The message I get is Type mismatch: cannot convert from Entity<String> to Class<T>

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sending JSON to a GET request. GET has no body, how will you send a JSON to it? Can you post some more code to show what classes are being used. Which version of Resteasy is it?

Comment: I want to use an API rest which can return a list of cars when you use a GET. I managed to make it work. But now , ive noticed it could get a json in entry, like if i send json {money:500} it will return all the cars which cost 500.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have my answer. It's impossible.
It seems that reasteasy does not allow body in a GET request